# Enmascarar input text javascript

Tags: javascript, html, entrada

Quiero enmascarar un input text con el siguiente formato: Aa-1234, donde las 2 letras son las siglas de estados de Estados Unidos, separado por un guión, y los 4 números son el zip code de 4 dígitos: ¿cómo lo podría hacer con javascript?

Comment: Has probado algo? Podrías poner tú código?

Comment: Osea quieres formatear el input para que solo reciba informacion de esa forma, y debe ser tal cual la muestras alli?

Comment: no he probado nada, si debe ser asi, pero valido la escritura con una expresión regular y funciona, pero lo que requiero es mediante se tipea adapte al formato

Comment: @WilmerMorgado pero igual debe escribri bajo ese formato, al menos que tengas algo mas en emnte por ejemplo que si escribo, Texas, lo que hace el input sea Tx, eso quieres?

Comment: lo que requiero es que no le permita escribir numeros sino se ha escrito las letras y que el "-" se coloque automatico, luego solo acepte numericos

Comment: @WilmerMorgado lo que se podria hacer es dos inputs, uno al lado del otro, en uno solo acepta letras bajo un formato, y en el otro solo numeros, y luego concatenarlos

Comment: umm ya lo había pensado pero tendría que modificar toda una web que ya esta lista jejeje.

Comment: @WilmerMorgado no crea que debas cambiar todo solo esa parte

Comment: Si pero son varios formularios que solicitan ese dato

Comment: En EEUU los códigos postales tienen 5 dígitos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Has probado esta librería JQuery?

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Hace exactamente lo que deseas. No valida la entrada del usuario, formatea el `input text` para introducir los datos con la máscara que le pases.

En tu caso se instanciaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#id_input").mask("aa-9999");
```

Comment: Si pero no funciona, es una app con phonega.

Comment: Phonegap no debería ser un impedimento. JQuery es totalmente compatible con Phonegap y sus librerías no suelen dar problemas.

Comment: bueno ya he revisado y no me funciono

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo bien a qué te refieres con la palabra enmascarar pero creo que tu fin es validar que el texto que proporciona el usuario a través del input tenga el formato que deseas, en este caso es algo como "us-1234" o "us-2375" etc. Para validar que una cadena dada cumple el formato requerido puedes valerte de expresiones regulares.

La expresión regular que modela el formato anterior es la siguiente:

```
^us-(\d{4})$
```

Lo anterior representa que al inicio de la cadena tiene que estar la letra u seguida de una s y un guion y después 4 números entre 0-9, el final de la cadena es el signo $.

Para que puedas usar esto en tu applicación necesitas emplearlo de la siguiente forma:

```
 exprZip = /^us-(\d{4})$/;   //tu expresión regular
 exprZip.test(textoInput);   //pruebas la expresión regular con la cadena que leiste del input y la función regresará true o false.
```

Answer (score 1):

En los `input` puedes usar el atributo [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input#attr-pattern) junto a una expresión regular para asegurar que la entrada tiene el formato que quieres. Lo malo es que todavía no está soportado por todos los navegadores: funcionará para Chrome, Firefox, Opera o IE10+, pero no funcionará bien con Safari.

Así lo que tendrías que hacer es buscar una expresión regular que se ajuste a lo que quieres. La idea sería algo como esto:

- 2 letras (que podrían ser cualquiera o las que quieras, pero esto complicará la expresión  regular)
- 1 guión
- 5 dígitos (aunque en la pregunta dices 4, los códigos postales en EEUU tiene 5 dígitos)

Así podrías tener una expresión regular como esta: `^[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{5}$` que combinada con el atributo `pattern` quedaría así:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{5}$" placeholder="ll-ddddd" />
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Otra opción (en caso de que `pattern` no funcione) sería hacerlo con JavaScript, con la misma expresión regular. A la hora de enviar el formulario, se comprobaría con JavaScript si el campo cumple el formato que quieres y si no, se muestra un mensaje de error y no se envía.

En JavaScript se vería así:

```js
document.getElementById("miform").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  var estado = document.getElementById("estado-cp").value;
  if (estado.match("^[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{5}$")) {
    alert("Cumple el patron");
  } else {
    alert("No cumple el patron");
    e.preventDefault(); // no se envia el formulario
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="miform">
  <input type="text" id="estado-cp" />
  <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

---

Ahora, sabiendo que el número de estados es limitado (50) y que hay algunos casos especiales (los territorios, código para extranjero), podrías limitar aún más las dos letras que se admiten a simplemente las que sean válidas (p.e.: AL, AK, TX...) y la expresión regular podrías ser así:

```
^[AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|MH|MA|MI|FM|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|VI|WA|WV|WI|WY]{2}-[0-9]{5}$
```

Comment: Ya resolví gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @WilmerMorgado Genial :D. ¿Cómo lo resolviste al final? Por favor, comparte el método con el que lo conseguiste al final

Comment: Asi lo resolvi cadenaFinal=this.value[0]+this.value[1]+"-"+this.value[2]+this.value[3]+this.value[4]+this.value[5];

Comment: Eso sólo limita el tamaño de la entrada pero no su contenido. ¿Qué pasa si el usuario entra 45abdhf que sería una cadena inválida?¿se admitiría?

Comment: No ya que le coloque un maxlength al input.

Comment: Pero lo que comentas sólo controla la longitud de la entrada y no su contenido. Los usuarios puedes escribir valores que no cumplen con el formato que quieres y tu solución lo admitirá mientras que mi respuesta o la de Pak Lei Chong hacen las dos cosas